# How to do Bessel function solution for vector curl?

Tags: vectors, bessel-functions

Consider the equations
$$\textbf j=\mu\textbf B$$
$$\nabla \wedge \textbf B=\mu_0\textbf j=\mu_0\mu\textbf B$$
where $\mu_0, \ \mu$ are constants. Then,
$$\nabla \wedge \textbf B=\mu_0\mu\textbf B$$
which in cyclindrical coordinates ${\bf B} = (B_\rho,B_\theta,B_z)$ leads to a Bessel function solution
$$B_z = B_0 J_0(\mu_0\mu \rho) \\ B_\theta = B_0J_1(\mu_0\mu \rho) \\ B_\rho = 0$$

How do I do this? Isn't Bessel solution for Laplace equation, not curl?

Comment: Can't it be because $\text{grad}(\text{div}(\vec{v}))=\Delta \vec{v}+\text{rot}(\text{rot}(\vec{v}))$?

Comment: The divergence of a curl is zero: $\nabla\cdot(\nabla\times B) = 0\implies \nabla\cdot B = 0$ and the curl of curl is
$$\nabla\times (\nabla \times B) = \nabla(\nabla\cdot B) - \nabla^2 B = -\nabla^2B$$ Using this you can derive $\nabla^2 B \propto B$ so $B$ satisfy a Poisson equation.